Raspberry Pi, Relay Module and 5V pump power dips / monitor flickering
I have an issue with my Raspberry Pi + Relay to control a pump. The relay module works fine and I can switch the pump on/off. However, if I switch the pump on for more than a few seconds, the monitor connected to my Raspberry Pi stops displaying the screen (it goes black).
My main setup is this:

Raspberry Pi w/ Monitor (HDMI), Mouse, Keyboard (Powered with its own supply)
4 Channel 5V Relay Module (Sunfounder)
Low volt DC pump with 5V Power Source (External, own supply)
Cables for +/-

Based on research on how to use a relay module, I set it up like so (picture included below):

RPi GND to Relay Module GND
RPi 3.3V to Relay Module VNC
RPi GPIO pins to Relay Module IN 1/2/3/4 (in my case, Board Pin 11)
Pump GND to Relay #1 NO
5V Power VNC to Pump VNC
5V Power GND to Relay #1 COM


I don't want to continue using this relay or using higher voltage pumps until I know for sure what causes this issue. Any help would be great - thanks.

Does the screen content recover if you restart only the monitor?

I'm guessing your 5v supply isn't enough to run the pi, display, and pump at the same time. It isn't clear from your question if you are driving the pump from an external supply, or the one on the pi?

the 5V supply is an external one only used for the pump, as shown in picture too. edited post to show that. @Jens the screen recovers after the pump goes off from the switch

Why do you supply relay coil power from Rasberry Pi? You seem to have one of those modules that have optoisolators and it should let you power the relay coils from a separate supply. Have you read the relay module manual?

What is VNC? Please use the abbreviation only after you have mentioned the term in full.

@Justme That might be the issue but I did read it can support the relay module in this case, since I'm using just one relay and it only draws 15-20 mA for the coil. For testing purposes, I am only trying to actively use one or two. The 3.3v output on the Raspberry Pi (from what I read) should be able to give up to 50 mA.
